# Proportional sized UIImageView in a UITableVIewCell is not behaving correctly all the time

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, constraints, uistoryboard

I have a UIImage in a tableview cell that I want to show in a circle.  When my table is rendered the first time the images are shown in a diamond shape instead of a circle, but when I go to that same screen after the first time  the images are rendered in circle.  I have found the problem, but I don't know the solution.  Here's the problem:  In the storyboard the UIImage view has a width and height set to 135, this is a random number because I assumed that I could overwrite it with the following two constraints in the storyboard:  1) a constraint that sets the height proportional to the superview's height and 2) a 1:1 ratio for the height and the width of the UIImage.  Here's the snapshot of my constraints:

[image]

I added prints to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath where I change the layout to a circle to see the UIImage width.  The first time it prints 135 and the second time it prints 100.  This means that the proportional size constraints weren't effective in the first round, but they are effective after.  I tried to set the fixed height and width in the storyboard to zero but that didn't help, it showed the image in a square.  How can I enforce the proportional constraints all the time?  Or disable the fixed size properties for this particular view?  Thanks!

P.S.  Here's the code inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath that changes the layout to a circle (nothing else in that method that touches the image or the layout):

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
cell.imageView.image = data.image
```

Comment: what is your imageView's content mode?

Comment: The content mode is scale to fill.

Comment: why not aspect fit? scale to fill will stretch your images.

Comment: Yes i does stretch the image but it has nothing to do with the frame size.

Comment: try using your code in TableViewWillDisplayCell delegate

Comment: I just tried it in TableViewWillDisplayCell and it didn't work.  The same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload table in viewWillLayoutSubViews.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The program hangs in updateTableView recursively calling itself by calling the reloadData.